# Xcopy jpg files from subfolders of "%~dp0" using wildcard

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, xcopy

I have one folder on my desktop `Test`, and in this folder I have two folders, `WorkingFolder\Bilder` and `Station 1`. So the structure looks like this:

> ```
> Test\WorkingFolder\Bilder
> Test\Station 1
> ```

Within `Test\` (the main folder) I have the batch file. I need to be able to move or copy the `.jpg` files from `Test\Station 1` into `Test\WorkingFolder\Bilder`. For this I have been using `XCopy`.

The problem is that I CANNOT use the name of the copy-from folder in `XCOPY`, because the batch file will be used on several similarily structured folders, but with different path names. So I have been trying to use `%~dp0` instead:
[image: Explaining Image]

My code is:

```
md WorkingFolder\Bilder
xcopy /s "%~dp0\*.jpg"  WorkingFolder\Bilder\
```

What I try to write is, copy all `.jpg` within the subfolders of `%~dp0`, `%~dp0` being the folder where the batch file is in, and its subfolder where the images are located `Station 1`, and put them in `WorkingFolder\Bilder`.

Problem is no files are copied. Only when I DIRECTLY refer to `Station 1` in `Xcopy`, then the files are copied. I need to be able to refer to all subdirectories to `%~dp0` and not like subdirectories to `%~dp0\example`.

Please help me!

Comment: Not a solution, but you forgot to include `%~dp0` in your destination directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) reports the following error:

> ```cmd
> Cannot perform a cyclic copy
> ```

This happens because the destination directory is located in the source directory tree.

You could try to use the [`robocopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) instead and exclude the destination directory:

```cmd
robocopy "%~dp0." "%~dp0WorkingFolder\Builder" "*.jpg" /S /XD "%~dp0WorkingFolder"
```